# Can't get pip3 to work with python 3.4 on Yosemite

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to get pip3 to work with python 3.4.  pip appears to be on my system already, but I want to make a soft link to it in /usr/local/bin, and I can't seem to do the right thing.  Whatever I try, I something like this:

```
sudo pip3 install pillow
Password:
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

Here's where pip appears to be:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages 
saul@Newton ✓ ls
README              easy-install.pth        pip-1.5.6.dist-info     setuptools-2.1.dist-info
__pycache__         easy_install.py         pkg_resources.py        setuptools-8.2.1-py3.4.egg
_markerlib          pip             setuptools          setuptools.pth

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages 
saul@Newton ✓ ls pip
__init__.py _vendor     baseparser.py   download.py locations.py    req.py      util.py
__main__.py backwardcompat  cmdoptions.py   exceptions.py   log.py      runner.py   vcs
__pycache__ basecommand.py  commands    index.py    pep425tags.py   status_codes.py wheel.py

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages 
saul@Newton ✓ ls pip/commands
__init__.py bundle.py   freeze.py   install.py  search.py   uninstall.py    wheel.py
__pycache__ completion.py   help.py     list.py     show.py     unzip.py    zip.py
```

Can you tell me if there is an installation step I've missed?  If not where should the pip3 link that I make in /usr/local/bin point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that the pip syntax had changed from python 2 to python 3, or perhaps it's always just been masked from me by shell scripts.  Anyway, I  found something on python.org, and tried

```
python3   -m pip install pillow
```

and it worked like a charm.  I still want to write

```
pip3 install pillow
```

like the big kids, but I'll just write a little script.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a few things.

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python3 distribute_setup.py
```

Then:

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

These steps might change your pip command, so you'd have to try pip-2.7 or pip2.7 to get the old pip.

These are where my pip3 links point:

```
pip3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.4.2/bin/pip3
pip3.4 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.4.2/bin/pip3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Pip command can be used to install Python 3.4 packages on Yosemeite:

```
pip-3.4 <package-name>
```

The package is provided by MacPorts as `py34-pip`.